# Listing adjacent cells

Tags: python

I have a 570 x 800 matrix with id values. What I would like to do if find the adjacent neighbors for each item. The max number of neighbors would be 8 unless the cell is along a boundary. In that case, there would be three neighbors. I want to append the neighbors to a list. I saw the posting for finding neighbors when each cell has x and y coordinates which was very helpful, but how would modify the code with no coordinates. The ids come in as a string which is fine because I use it as a key in a dictionary. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Edit your question with the post you are referring to, perhaps it will be easier to explain the changes needed relative to the (x,y) coordinate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*code with no coordinates*? Do you mean like this:

```
XMAX = 800
YMAX = 570

NEIGHBOURS = [(-1, -1), (0, -1), (1, -1), (-1, 0), (1, 0), (-1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 1)]

matrix = range(XMAX * YMAX)

def all_neighbours(m):
    for i in xrange(len(m)):
        ns = []
        y, x = divmod(i, XMAX)
        for u, v in NEIGHBOURS:
            ux = u + x
            vy = v + y
            if 0 <= ux < XMAX and 0 <= vy < YMAX:
                ns.append(ux + vy * YMAX)
        yield i, ns

if __name__ == '__main__':

    for field, neighbours in all_neighbours(matrix):
        print field, neighbours
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that what you're trying to do is construct an eight-connected grid on the matrix, and that the position of item in the the matrix defines an x- and y- co-ordinate, you can use something like this:

```
def eight_connected_neighbours( xmax, ymax, x, y ):
    """The x- and y- components for a single cell in an eight connected grid

    Parameters
    ----------
    xmax : int
        The width of the grid

    ymax: int
        The height of the grid

    x : int
        The x- position of cell to find neighbours of

    y : int 
        The y- position of cell to find neighbours of

    Returns
    -------
    results : list of tuple
        A list of (x, y) indices for the neighbours    
    """
    results = []
    for dx in [-1,0,1]:
        for dy in [-1,0,1]:
            newx = x+dx
            newy = y+dy
            if (dx == 0 and dy == 0):
                continue
            if (newx>=0 and newx<xmax and newy >=0 and newy<ymax):
                results.append( (newx, newy) )
    return results
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks so much for your example.  I follow it, but I'm not sure what to input for x and y when I run the code?  When I run the code, do I type:  eight_connected_neighbours(570,800,x,y)?  Thanks for your input.

Comment: @LindaVasil - you've got it exactly right, but I've added a docstring to reflect what is really going on

Answer (score 2):

Let me give an alternate answer with `numpy`, which is a library you might want to consider if you're doing anything a bit more heavy duty with your data. The advantage with this method is the extensibility to the number of nearest neighbors with the parameter `k`. The setup:

```
from numpy import *

k = 1

# Create the nearest neighbors
Xidx, Yidx = mgrid[-k:k+1,-k:k+1]

# Remove the center (0,0) index
center = (Xidx==0) & (Yidx==0)
Xidx = Xidx[~center]
Yidx = Yidx[~center]
```

Now you can access the nearest neighbors with `A[Xidx+dx, Yidx+dy]` where `dx` and `dy` are the offsets for the `x` and `y` coordinates.

**Example**

Let's take a random matrix:

```
A = random.random((5,5))
print A
```

which for me looks like:

```
[[ 0.90779297  0.91195651  0.32751438  0.44830373  0.2528675 ]
 [ 0.02542108  0.52542962  0.28203009  0.35606998  0.88076027]
 [ 0.08955781  0.98903843  0.86881875  0.21246095  0.92005691]
 [ 0.57253561  0.08830487  0.06418296  0.59632344  0.53604546]
 [ 0.7646322   0.50869651  0.00229266  0.26363367  0.64899637]]
```

Now we can view the nearest neighbors with

```
dx, dy = 2,1

print "Cell value A[%i,%i] = %f " % (dx, dy, A[dx,dy])
print "k=%i nearest neighbors: "%k, A[Xidx+dx, Yidx+dy]
```

Giving:

```
Cell value A[2,1] = 0.989038 
k=1 nearest neighbors:  [ 0.02542108  0.52542962  0.28203009  0.08955781  0.86881875 0.57253561  0.08830487  0.06418296]
```

**Bonus**

As mentioned, by changing `k` you can easily get the next nearest neighbors, and next-next neighbors, etc... In addition, the ability to index a higher order array (say a tensor of rank 3) is now possible by adding an additional variable `Zidx` in a similar way.

**Caveats**

This works nicely when you go to the rightmost and bottom of your matrix - you'll get smaller lists (as you specified you wanted). However, `numpy` indexing (and Python) as well, *wraps around*, so an index of `-1` will give you the last element. Thus asking for the offset at `0,0` will still give you eight entries by wrapping around. The other answers here show a good way to check for this.

If you want to grab something on the left side edge (and you really don't want to use an if statement), you might change the index as such (making sure to remove the center element as above):

```
# Create the nearest neighbors (ON THE LEFT EDGE)
Xidx_left, Yidx_left = mgrid[0:k+1,-k:k+1]
```

Comment: Wow, I do appreciate you answer very much!!  When I tried the i, j methods for obtaining rows and columns I would get an error.  I was trying to approach it like a matlab code.  Thanks very much!!

Comment: Is there anyway to pop the wrapped around values for the boundaries cells?  Are they always in a fixed location?

Comment: @LindaVasil I would just add a check to see if we were at the boundary, if so I would make a different index than `corner`. You wouldn't `pop` a value in numpy, you would index over what you want. Like I said you only have to worry about the top and left side edge for your `if` condition.

Comment: @LindaVasil I added an example for the left side index, you can adapt as needed.

Comment: Thanks for all your help!  I really appreciate it.  This is land use grid...I originally coded it in ArcGIS with measuring distances between cells (converted to points).  This ate up all my memory and would take hours to run.  This method is much faster!

Comment: @LindaVasil No problem, and welcome to Stack Overflow (SO)! If you've found an answer useful, please upvote it to help rank the answers for others. In addition, it's considered good form to accept the answer that was the most useful (if any) - people are more apt to answer your next question that way.