# Changing the variables around strings in a list of lists

Tags: list, python-3.x

I am programming a minesweeper game and i have encountered a problem and i can't solve it on my own. I want to change the 0's around the M's to 1 if one M is close to it, a 2 if two mines is close to it and so on. I have written this code:

```
hiddenfield =  [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'M', 0, 0, 0, 'M'],
            [0, 0, 0, 'M', 0, 0, 0, 'M', 'M', 'M'],
            [0, 0, 'M', 0, 'M', 0, 0, 'M', 0, 'M'],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 'M', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 'M', 0, 'M', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 'M', 0, 'M', 'M', 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 'M', 0, 0, 0, 'M', 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 'M', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 'M', 'M', 0, 'M', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            ['M', 0, 0, 'M', 0, 0, 0, 0, 'M', 0]] 

for i in range(0,len(hiddenfield)):
    for j in range(0,len(hiddenfield)):
        try:
            if hiddenfield[i][j] == 'M':            
                hiddenfield[i+1][j] += 1
                hiddenfield[i-1][j] += 1
                hiddenfield[i][j+1] += 1
                hiddenfield[i][j-1] += 1
                hiddenfield[i+1][j-1] += 1
                hiddenfield[i-1][j+1] += 1
                hiddenfield[i+1][j+1] += 1
                hiddenfield[i-1][j-1] += 1
        except IndexError:
            continue

def showMineFieldHidden(hiddenfield):
    border = list(range(0,len(hiddenfield)))
    row = [' ']+border
    i = 0
    for rows in [border]+hiddenfield:
        print(row[i], end=' ')
        i += 1
        for lines in rows:
            print(lines, end=' ')
        print()
```

but all i get is this:

```
    0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
  0 0 0 0 1 1 M 1 0 1 M 
  1 0 0 2 M 2 1 1 M M M 
  2 0 1 M 2 M 0 0 M 1 M 
  3 0 1 2 1 M 0 0 1 0 1 
  4 0 1 M 1 M 1 1 0 0 0 
  5 0 1 1 M 1 M M 2 1 0 
  6 0 0 0 M 0 1 2 M 1 0 
  7 0 1 1 M 1 0 1 1 1 0 
  8 0 M M 3 M 1 0 0 0 0 
  9 M 1 1 M 2 1 1 0 M 0
```

would really appreciate some help.

Comment: As a another idea - I'd make a mine object (should hold it's own location), and each would have a method that receives a board and increments by 1 all of it's surrounding locations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 problems:

1. if there is an index error before the end you skip the rest
2. you overwrite other mines

   ```
   for i in range(0, len(hiddenfield)):
       for j in range(0, len(hiddenfield)):
       if hiddenfield[i][j] == 'M':
               if hiddenfield[i + 1][j] != 'M':
                   try:
                       hiddenfield[i + 1][j] += 1
                   except IndexError:
                       pass
               if hiddenfield[i + 1][j] != 'M':
                   try:
                       hiddenfield[i - 1][j] += 1
                   except IndexError:
                       pass
               #and so on ..... :(
   ```

This is awful and therefore you should put this into a funtion

```
def update_cell(x, y):
    try:
        if hiddenfield[x][y] != 'M':
            hiddenfield[x][y] += 1
    except IndexError:
        pass

for i in range(0, len(hiddenfield)):
    for j in range(0, len(hiddenfield)):
        if hiddenfield[i][j] == 'M':
            update_cell(i - 1, j - 1)
            update_cell(i - 1, j)
            update_cell(i - 1, j + 1)
            update_cell(i, j - 1)
            update_cell(i, j + 1)
            update_cell(i + 1, j - 1)
            update_cell(i + 1, j)
            update_cell(i + 1, j + 1)
```

Now that looks way better :)

Answer (score 0):

I would start by storing the indexes of your bombs in a list.  Then I would try using a function to get all neighboring elements given a location.

check out [Listing adjacent cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245898/listing-adjacent-cells)

Then you can update this function to take an additional parameter which would be a  function ex increment or decrement to be executed on all adjacent cells found